# Strange behavior in Javascript enhanced for...in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I am making a Javascript game with the canvas tag, and I am using an enhanced for loop to update the player positions.

In brief:

```
var actors = new Array();

var player = new Actor(0, 0, img);

actors[0] = player;

function update_positions() {
    //position 1
    for(var a in actors) {
        //position2
        a.xpos += a.xvel;
        a.ypos += a.yvel;
    }
}
```

Just outside of the for loop at position 1, I can access the correct value of actors[0].xvel. Inside the for loop at position 2, a.xvel is undefined. Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: Please see this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886179/why-does-javascript-turn-array-indexes-into-strings-when-iterating/1886259#1886259

Comment: [Don't use for-in-loops for arrays at all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: 2015 update: you want `for (var a of actors)`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/For...in) statement is meant to be used to iterate over *object properties*, by looking your code seems that `actors` is an Array (you are setting the initial element with index `0`).

This statement will also [crawl up](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#forin) the prototype chain, if you have extended the `Array.prototype` those properties will be iterated, and also the order of iteration is not warranted.

I would recommend you to avoid [problems](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/) and iterate using a normal for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < actors.length; i++) {
    actors[i].xpos += actor.xvel;
    actors[i].ypos += actor.yvel;
}
```

If I'm wrong, and `actors` is not an Array, I would recommend you to use the `hasOwnProperty` method, to ensure that the property exists in the object itself, not up somewhere in the prototype chain:

```
for (var name in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    //
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it looks like you're trying to access object properties on the name, not the value here. the index, in this case '0', gets assigned to 'a' in the for/in loop.

what you want to do is access the value of the array member, ie: actors[a].

try this:

```
for(var a in actors) { // a=0 the first time around the loop,  
    actor = actors[a]; // same thing as actors[0];
    actor.xpos += actor.xvel;
    actor.ypos += actor.yvel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `actors[a].xpos` instead of just `a.xpos`.

See here for more info on [JavaScript for-in loops](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_loop_for_in.asp).

Answer (score 2):

The `for (x in y)` construct iterates through the indexes of an array, not its members.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library:

```
_.each( actors, function(a) {
    a.xpos += a.xvel;
    a.ypos += a.yvel;
});
```

or if you don't want to use underscore but are using JQuery anyway, then you can do:

```
$.each( actors, function(i, a) {
    a.xpos += a.xvel;
    a.ypos += a.yvel;
});
```

One nice feature of this functional pattern of iteration is that you can use `var` to declare variables in the loop that are scoped to the body of the loop, which helps avoid getting bitten by the odd variable scoping rules of JavaScript.