# Why does javascript turn array indexes into strings when iterating?

Tags: javascript

This Javascript logic puzzles me. I'm creating an array and setting the first element of it to a number. When I interate through it using a "for" loop Javascript turns the array key into a string. Why? I want it to stay a number.

```
stuff = [];
stuff[0] = 3;

for(var x in stuff) {
    alert(typeof x);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because you're looping through the array using `for...in` which is generally used for looping over properties of objects. The javascript engine is probably casting to a string because the string type is suitable for names of object properties.

Try this more traditional approach:

```
stuff = [];
stuff[0] = 3;

for(var i=0; i<stuff.length; i++) {
    var x = stuff[i];
    alert(typeof x);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`for..in` is not designed to iterate over Arrays. Use a C-style for loop instead.

Reference: [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in#Description)

Answer (score 4):

The `for .. in` loop in Javascript iterates through the *properties* of the object. In Javascript, property names are strings and arrays are just objects with a bunch of properties that happen to look like numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The `for...in` statement should be used to iterate over *object properties*, for Arrays use a simple `for` loop:

```
var stuff = [];
stuff.push(3);

for(var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
  alert(stuff[i]);
}
```

Why shouldn't use `for...in` with arrays?

1. It crawls up the prototype chain, it will iterate over properties defined up in the `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype`.
2. The order of iteration is *not* guaranteed anyhow.

More details on a recently answered question:

- [Strange behavior in Javascript enhanced for…in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885317/strange-behavior-in-javascript-enhanced-for-in-loop/1885365#1885365)

Answer (score 3):

Avoid for-in in [performance-critical](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2) functions.

- `The for-in loop requires the script engine to build a list of all the enumerable properties`, and check for duplicates in that list, before it can start the enumeration.
- `The for-in loop breaks when you extend Array object using prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is very easy in JavaScript to switch to associative arrays, which are in fact not arrays but objects. The `for..in` loop however works on objects, which indices are strings.